# Is the assign operation atomic in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I would like to know if the assign operation is atomic in PostgreSQL. I have a table with counter that will be incremented from multiple threads like this:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE Id = 10
```

Is it possible that multiple postgresql-threads remember and update the same value causing data loss?

```
-- Counter = 111
THREAD #1: UPDATE SomeTable SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE Id = N
THREAD #2: UPDATE SomeTable SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE Id = N
-- Counter must be 113 even if two threads update it simultaneously
```

Do PostgreSQL guarantee the atomicy of increment operations?

Comment: Can't answer your question, but opinion that might help- I don't care for incrementing 'count' fields...there is no log that can be traced to show you why/how the count got that high, your just know it's that value.  Instead...there is an event that caused that count to increment, record the event in a table and do something along the lines of "select key,count(1) from table group by key" to return the count you need.

Comment: **Atomic** is the wrong term for this question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity . It's **Isolation** that you want to look into.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to this, it depends on your transaction isolation level and what level of 'safe' you need (e.g. is it OK if the TX fails on a concurrent modification?).
You can read up on this over here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html. To achieve what you want here, you would likely need to run your code in a transaction with a serializable isolation level.

You don't say much on what you are actually trying to achieve, but maybe an approach using a Sequence is a better choice for your problem?:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: This is not true. Actually even the lowest transaction isolation level, i.e. read uncommitted, doesn't introduce risk for the given approach. You can test it e.g. that way:

CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT 0 as counter;

-- and in multiple consoles:
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
BEGIN

LOOP
 EXIT WHEN EXTRACT ( second FROM clock_timestamp() )::integer % 15 = 0;
end loop;

FOR I IN 1 .. 10000 LOOP
UPDATE test SET counter = counter + 1;
END LOOP;
END $$;

Comment: You are just show-casing read-uncommitted behavior (which specifically allows those side effects)? You'd run faster into issues with sth like repeatable-read. Note: All of them are still 'safe' depending on the level of safety you need. P.S.: You'll have a hard time reproducing sequencing issues like that on a modern machine ...

Comment: From my experience, it is possible to reproduce sequencing issues. But I don't believe it is possible to proove there is any risk in that case. You can see it as a kind of challenge :)
By the way, using sequence may be good solution, too (I mentioned it in the initial version of my answer).

Comment: Let's not resort to evidence based claims. The key part is that the isolation level does matter a lot. In the simplest example a repeatable-read TX will fail on concurrent modifications. It is still 'safe', as the thread can re-issue the TX until it eventually wins. Which level makes sense really depends on the other stuff going on in the transaction.

Comment: OK, I admit I cannot be so sure for the real READ UNCOMMITTED. But what justifies me here, up to certain point, is that selecting this level in PostgreSQL means selecting READ COMMITED. So dirty read won't happen here.

Answer (score 0):

The way you provided is safe since the values aren't fixed. All the transactions are counting up the value from a snaphot visible only to them.
There is a lot of information on concurrency in the documentation:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.  That's the point of a transactional RDBMS (i.e., not MySQL running MyISAM or MEMORY).  A transaction either completes 100% successfully or fails 100% completely and rolls back.  You may also want to read up on [transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html), although this doc only touches on the subject.  The tutorial there essentially uses the exact scenario you describe as an example.

You're not going to lose data, but you may run in to locking issues.  See the doc on [concurrency](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/mvcc.html).